# What's the difference between ON_NOTIFY, ON_CONTROL, ON_CONTROL_REFLECT?

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi, event-handling

I always struggle to keep all these macros straight in my head. Is there an easy way to remember them, and which to use in a given scenario?

Specifically, does one of these allow a dialog to intercept/detect messages to child control windows? e.g Can the dialog register an interest when IDC_MY_CONTROL gets a WM_PAINT message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ON_NOTIFY handles WM_NOTIFY messages.  ON_CONTROL handles WM_COMMAND messages from controls.  ON_CONTROL_REFLECT is for handling messages sent to a parent from the child class.